# Writing a compiler in PHP

Tags: php, compiler-construction

A few years ago I started working on a few ideas about a programming language and as I was so excited about them I just wanted to see how they would works, so I decide to write a very simple compiler for that. As I'm more comfortable and more experienced in PHP, I just took a look at to see if it's possible to write a compiler in PHP and very soon after that I found that yes, it's possible. So I start making that and fortunately everything was okay and now it's working fine.

Those days I just wanted a place to start working on my ideas, and as PHP was fast in development (no need to compile), I had MySQL on my hands also, and debugging was really easy, etc.

Now I want to extend this simple compiler, and that's where I need your advise. My main question is "Is PHP a right tool for a compiler project?". Just suppose that I'm not gonna release it publicly, so just think about the PHP abilities to handle the task, not further problems like distribution.

I believe that it has some advantages. It's fast in development, I just edit the code and press the F5 on browser and I had my binary output right after that. I also made a text box there where I could write my simple codes, press the submit and then I had my binary output again. It was also fast to keeping and working on the parsed data in MySQL. But now I'm more worried about the script timeout for example. If it's gonna compile 10,000 lines of source code, it would timeout I guess. I know I can increase the timeout, but still worried about that. Also I know that PHP as a scripting language is (as I heard) 10 times slower rather a compiled-application.

So, do you think I have to switch-off to the C? (which I'm also okay with that also) ... or do you have any ideas if I could continue with my PHP back-end, but to handle more serious things and without facing critical mistakes?

**Update:**

Yes! the project is personal and for fun. You may consider that also!

Regarding application for a PHP-based compiler, yes, it's not a real-world compiler, but imagine if you want to share your ideas with others, it would be great if you gave them a web form to write their code, press the button and download the binary code. It's not my goal, however, I just wondering about that.

Regarding Lex/Yacc, my ideas was more about optimizing the final binary code, so I needed something more than just generating a binary code via Lex/Yacc.

Comment: I can't quite get my head around why you'd think that running a compiler via a browser is easier than the command line.

Comment: also, this is the first compiler I've ever heard of that used a database.

Comment: @Spudley yeah, I stored parsed data in mysql tables, and then working on them via queries ...

Comment: Also lex/yacc or their GNU equivalents flex/bison

Comment: @nielsbot I know lex/yacc, but I wanted to experience that, however to see how much my ideas would works. they were mainly about optimization, so I didn't used lex/yacc as I needed something more deeply into generating the final binary ...

Comment: You can write a compiler in any language. But PHP is a poor choice indeed. Any language without a decent pattern matching support will be a poor choice unavoidably leading to tons of boilerplate code.

Comment: @SK-logic regex is enough, huh?

Comment: @Mahdi, what do you mean? Yes, you actually can write a compiler in a modern regex language. You don't need a Turing-complete language to write a compiler. But it won't be a pleasant experience. Or, you're talking about an alternative to pattern matching? Then you're wrong, regexps are not nearly a replacement.

Comment: @SK-logic could you please write an answer with more explanations? I really want to know more about your opinion. thanks, it would really helps ... :)

Comment: @SK-logic I actually do everything with regex or some other simple alternatives ... I'd face some difficulties in the future???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to write a compiler in any language (even some non-Turing-complete languages can be used). But in order to make life easier you'll need certain language features which are missing from PHP, and since it is a pretty low-level language, it is not quite possible to add such features to the language.

A decent language for implementing compilers must contain:

- Some form of [algebraic data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type), it is relevant even for a fully dynamic languages (like Lisp)
- [Pattern matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching), the more powerful and expressive - the better. Writing AST transformations without pattern matching is a pain.

This is a bare minimum. Having some decent native support for graphs is an advantage. Having an embedded support for parsing is quite useful (but parsing is not that important in general). Having an access to Prolog or Datalog in runtime is extremely useful (but it should be easy to implement your own Prolog in PHP).

Comment: hey, thanks! I would dig more on these things as I thought they would never bother me if I'm going with PHP alone. Thanks again, it was really helpful! :)

Comment: P.S. I really meant *low*--level (in terms of a level of abstraction, not a degree of separation from hardware). PHP is not a high level enough to be a *flexible* language in which new language features can be added using the language itself.

Comment: I do not see why you would need a more flexible language to write a compiler. Surely you have some great advantages in a very flexible language like Ruby, but as long as you can tokenize a string you can write a compiler.

Answer (score 7):

PHP is not the ideal environment for writing compilers.  Is it doable?  Sure.  Should you do it?  I am vehemently opposed to writing a compiler in a high-level language like PHP.  I'm also opposed to unnecessarily reinventing the wheel.

If it's for fun, I say go for it, but I don't see any practical uses for a PHP-driven compiler at this time.

Comment: thanks for mentioning the fun ... yeah, it's somehow for fun and just experiencing new things ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Webjawns say:  but I don't see any practical uses for a PHP-driven compiler at this time.
 So????
Smarty - is a compiller!!!

If your compiller is just for fun, or specific, php-related use  - it is good idea took the php as environment.

But if your compiller has a performance requirements or memory restrictions - it is very bad idea to use PHP for it.

Comment: thank you mentioning about performance requirements! BTW, it's not gonna do anything with PHP, it's just based on PHP :)

Comment: You should make note of the huge difference between a **compiler** which takes source code all the way to binary machine code versus a transcoder which takes one source code and transforms it into another. Smarty is a transcoder.

Comment: A compiler transforms one language into another, it's the definition of compiler. A lot of compilers do not go to binary code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a computer programmers gag that sounds something like:

> *Rookie:* Why is C considered to "run faster"/"use less memory"/"insert other optimization comparison here" than Java?
>   *Mentor:* Because the Java compiler is written in C while the C compiler is written in C (with traces of assembly for optimization).

Almost all compilers are written in C. The same thing goes for operating systems which are also almost all written in C. Almost all of the main prepacked libraries that any high level language uses are written in C. Almost all high-load servers (Apache & MySQL included) are written in C. Basically almost every mission critical piece of software is written in C.

With that in mind id's say:

I'd write a Tokenizer -> Parser -> Transcoder chain in PHP for fun - maybe even one with database storage what the heck; but i would be outputting text (source code for another language).

I wouldn't write a Compiler in PHP because i wouldn't want to be outputting binary files from PHP - not because it can't but because I don't like using strings for binary arithmetics.

The Compiler I'd write in C.

Comment: I like your comment, thanks! but I think you can write a compiler better than any compilers, no matter you're using C or PHP. I agree with you about the role and abilities of C, however I still think the logic behind the compiler is much more important. C and PHP both have the same things to deal with binary output, at the end ...

Comment: C is also a very poor choice for writing compilers (no pattern matching, no algebraic data types). It does not matter how fast your compiler is, but it is important how much effort you're ready to waste on implementing it. And before you start arguing, no, GCC is not written in C. GCC is written in a bunch of highly specialised DSLs (which are implemented on top of C).

Comment: The highly specialized DSL you are talking about ensure the architecture of GCC as a modular **collection** of compilers. The individual compilers themselves were written in C / C++. There are two dozen C compilers some of them aiming to be extremely small and/or to have no dependencies, which are all written in C. I guess you could say that the highly specialized DSL for GCC is more like a  very big config file to a C application.

Comment: @MihaiStancu, you're wrong again. Try reading GCC code, they're using Lisp-like DSLs all the way through. Or, for a more modern approach, see LLVM and Clang, and especially their collection of DSLs implemented in `TableGen` tool. C on its own does not provide any of the specific tools that you'll need for implementing a compiler. Therefore, there is no point in using plain C (or C++) for such a task, unless you want to have some specific fun (like with `tcc`, which started as an obfuscated C contest entry).